# How can a table stay inside the outer div element

Tags: html, css

I it possible to make a `TABLE` to stay inside the outer `CSS` div selector `content-inner` ?.

If i change to a small resolution, this table (that list record from a seach) will stay with fixed size, while the border around the table will have 8 px padding from right.

The table will leave the outer perimeter from the content-inner element.

I need to avoid the table to to leave the outer div.

Here is the CSS code i use for the table :

```
.table-list {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:15px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Here is the CSS code i use for the content-inner div:

```
.content-inner {
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /*padding: 24px;*/
    padding: 12px;
    /*min-height: 295px;*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with an example of your HTML?

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well

Comment: Yes ! https://jsfiddle.net/4s82pnu9/ here it is

Comment: i try overflow-x: scroll; it works but will affect smaller screen the best option would be to shrinck the table inside the content-inner div

Comment: I see it as slightly diferent @sabithpocker my table content is inside the table what i need is the entire table inside the outer div element.